# How to communicate between apple watch and ios app using phonegap?

Tags: cordova, watchkit, apple-watch

I am new on phonegap. i want to build an app for apple watch which can communicate with their host ios app. I don't know host app is builded  by phonegap or not ? So could i build an app for watch which can communicate with host app using phonegap ? in other word i want to create environment where i can communicate ios app and watch using phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is a type of shell that allows you to do things at a high level by handling all the iOS low level stuff.  Watch <-> iOS communication is handled by the Watch Connectivity system, which is a low level system.  It should be possible to add low level commands to your PhoneGap app to allow you to do what you want.  I'd suggest going through the Watch Connectivity docs and/or watching the Watch Connectivity WWDC session from last time:  [Go to Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html)   [Go to WWDC Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/713/)

Comment: Thank you so much @Owen Hartnett. Every thing is clear .

Comment: If that answered your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cordova plugin to handle the communication with the apple watch

Install the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apple-watch
```

Init the plugin

```
applewatch.init(function successHandler(appGroupId) {}, function errorHandler(){});
```

Send messages to the watch

```
applewatch.sendMessage(message, queueName, successHandler, errorHandler);
```

Listen for watch messages

```
applewatch.addListener(queueName, messageHandler);
```

And some other things, read the docs on https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-apple-watch